# How do I send requests in a for loop synchronously in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, request

I'm trying to make facebook api requests in a **for loop** using **request** module in nodejs. But I need to make the loop and request calls **synchronous**. What am I doing wrong?

```
    async function sendRequestAsync(sender, messageData) {
        await request({
            url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
            qs: {access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
            method: "POST",
            json: {
                recipient: {id: sender},
                message: messageData
            }
        });
     }

     function sendFoods (sender, results) {
         results.forEach(async result => {
             await request.sendRequestasync(sender, {text: result.cat});
             await request.sendRequestasync(sender, result.data);
             console.log(result);
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES8 Async/Await the script waits for resolving a promise before it continues the execution.

```
async function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let result = await req('http://google.com');
    console.log(result.resp.statusCode, i);
  };
};

function req(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url, function(err, resp, body) {
      if (err) { reject(err); }
      else { resolve({resp: resp, body: body}); }
    })
  })
};
```

[Try my live example](https://repl.it/@user0/SimultaneousPowerlessTrapezoids)

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. Just a quick question, what if I wanted catch resolve and reject separately with await?

Comment: You're welcome. Reject will throw an error, if you need it in the `result` variable, change `reject(err)` to `resolve(err)`, so the result will be the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your sendRequestAsync function should just return the promise directly from the request call rather than awaiting it. Await is really just syntactic sugar for .then ().